# $X$ infinite dimensional, $Y$ has finite dimension, $f:X\to Y$ linear. Is $f$ surjective?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ complex vextor spaces, $X$ infinite dimensional, $Y$ of finite dimension. Is $f$ surjective in general? My problem is, I can not use the formula $\dim X=\dim ker(f)+\dim Im (f)$, because $X$ is infinite. And it's not possible to write down a concrete Basis of $X$, if I remember correctly.

Ok: And after the first answer is given (thanks):  if $f$ is nonzero, if f surjective?

Comment: No, definitely not. One way to see it: take any linear map from some X to some finite dimensional Y. Now replace Y with a larger finite dimensional space Y', like $Y'=Y\oplus\mathbb R$. As a map into Y', f will not be surjective.

Comment: [MSE is a Q&A site](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) which aims to accumulate useful material for posterity, not a chat site. :) If you want to modify a question after it's been answered, it's perhaps best to post a separate question. (In the case at hand, it would be even better to think about _why_ the first answer _also answers your modified question_.)

Answer (score 1):

No. $f(x)=0_Y$ is a linear map, and definitely not surjective unless $Y$ is zero-dimensional.

Another example: polynomials in $X$ form a vector space $\mathbb{R}[X]$ over $\mathbb{R}$. The map
$$ T_n(p) = p \pmod{X^n}, $$
which spits out $p$ up to the term with an $X^{n-1}$ (so, for example, $T_1(X^2+2X+3) = 3$, $T_2(X^2+2X+3) = 2X+3$, and so on) is a linear map from $\mathbb{R}[X]$ to any space of polynomials with degree $m \geqslant n-1$, but is only surjective if $m=n-1$.

Comment: oh yes thanks, i want to omit this case... sorry. and if f is nonzero, follows f surjective?